# Third column of grid showing up when inspected

Tags: css

So my results are only supposed to be rendering across two columns in the grid, however, upon inspection, there is a third. Here is my CSS and the screenshot is attched. Any thoughts?

```
.grid {
            display: grid;
             grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        }

        .grid-item {
            padding: 16px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }

        .grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
            border-right: 1px solid black;
        }

        .grid-item:nth-last-child(-n + 2):nth-of-type(odd),
        .grid-item:last-child {
            border-bottom: none;
        }
```

[image]

Also when I have more results, the values are rendering all horizontally, instead of vertically.
Would the fact that many of the same styles are overrideen be the cause?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. Grids are not counted in columns/rows but grid tracks. If you have two columns then you need three tracks to be able to target the far edge of your grid when spanning items across it. It's also expected for automatically placed grid items to flow horizontally across the available cells.

Comment: @lawrence-witt I just edited the original post. How can I have them render as such?